# Django admin url shows "table or view does not exist" while using oracledb

Tags: python-3.x, django, oracle, python-oracledb, django-oracle

I am very beginner to django & oracle. Trying to connect oracledb from django using hr schema. Data is availabe to django model from database but it shows "table or view does not exist" when browsing admin url. I have the following tables on the database.

```
DJANGO_MIGRATIONS
DJANGO_CONTENT_TYPE
AUTH_PERMISSION
AUTH_GROUP
AUTH_GROUP_PERMISSIONS
AUTH_USER
AUTH_USER_GROUPS
AUTH_USER_USER_PERMISSIONS
DJANGO_ADMIN_LOG
```

Does django automatically migrate admin to the oracle database or I need to create them manually?